# How to create dynamic checkboxes based on values in a database, using AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to create dynamic checkboxes using AJAX so that on the basis of categories the number of checkboxes should appear on screen. I've sample code in HTML that I want to convert in JS.

HTML Code

```
<div id="check-awesome" class="form-group checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" id="History">
    <label for="History">
        <span></span>
        <span class="check"></span>
        <span class="box"></span>
        History
    </label>
</div>
```

AJAX Code

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type:'post',
            url:'/categories',
            contentType:'application/json',
            data: '{"_token":"<?php echo csrf_token() ?>"}',
            success:function(data) {
                for(i=0; i<=data.category_name.length;i ++)
                {
                    var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
                    checkbox.type="checkbox";
                    checkbox.value=data.category_name.category_id;
                    checkbox.id=data.category_name[i].category_name;
                    var label= document.createElement('label');
                    label.htmlFor=data.category_name[i].category_name;
                    var span=document.createElement('span');
                    label.appendChild(span);
                    var span1=document.createElement('span');
                    span1.className="check";
                    label.appendChild(span1);
                    var span2=document.createElement('span');
                    span2.className="box";
                    label.appendChild(span2);
                    label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data.category_name[i].category_name));
                    var div= document.getElementById('check-awesome');
                    div.appendChild(label);
                    div.appendChild(checkbox);
                }
                return div;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: did you try my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured out the mess actually I got messed up in the order of append actually these checkboxes are bit different and need to be append just after creation therefore the code should be like this.
Thank you everyone for help! :)

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $.ajax({
       type:'post',
       url:'/categories',
       contentType:'application/json',
       data: '{"_token":"<?php echo csrf_token() ?>"}',
       success:function(data) {
         for(i=0; i<=data.category_name.length;i ++)
           { 
             var div= document.createElement('div');
             div.id="check-awesome";
             div.className="form-group checkbox"
             var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
             checkbox.type="checkbox";
             checkbox.value=data.category_name.category_id;
             checkbox.id=data.category_name[i].category_name;
             div.appendChild(checkbox);
             var label= document.createElement('label');
             label.htmlFor=data.category_name[i].category_name;
             var span=document.createElement('span');
             label.appendChild(span);
             var span1=document.createElement('span');
             span1.className="check";
             label.appendChild(span1);
             var span2=document.createElement('span');
             span2.className="box";
             label.appendChild(span2);
             label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data.category_name[i].category_name));
             div.appendChild(label);
             var get_div=document.getElementById('checkboxparent');
             get_div.appendChild(div);
           }
         return get_div;
       }
     });
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you make a mistake in for loop.
Use operation '<' instead of '<=' if you process with an array.

Remember index of array start from 0 not 1

Answer (score 0):

You created div `check-awesom` in the loop. But you must declare it out of the loop. I used callback variable in function, so when your request success then function will call the function parameter with created div in his parameter

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
            function createChecboxes(requestEndCallback) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    url: '/categories',
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    data: '{"_token":"<?php echo csrf_token() ?>"}',
                    async: true, // do this for synchronous call to ajax 
                    success: function (data) {
                        var div = document.getElementById('check-awesome');
                        for (i = 0; i < data.category_name.length; i++) {
                            var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
                            checkbox.type = "checkbox";
                            checkbox.value = data.category_name.category_id;
                            checkbox.id = data.category_name[i].category_name;
                            var label = document.createElement('label');
                            label.htmlFor = data.category_name[i].category_name;
                            var span = document.createElement('span');
                            label.appendChild(span);
                            var span1 = document.createElement('span');
                            span1.className = "check";
                            label.appendChild(span1);
                            var span2 = document.createElement('span');
                            span2.className = "box";
                            label.appendChild(span2);
                            label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data.category_name[i].category_name));

                            div.appendChild(label);
                            div.appendChild(checkbox);
                        }
                        requestEndCallback(div)
                    }
                });
                return mydiv;
            }

            // call your function like this
            createChecboxes(function (createdDiv) {
                // use createdDiv in here
            })
        });
```

ps. As @Tri says, you also wrote `<=` instead of `<` in the for condition.

Comment: waiting for an ajax post is a bad idea... `Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check` http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

Answer (score 0):

You can add checkbox like this.

```
var place = document.getElementById('check-awesome');
for(i=0; i<=data.category_name.length;i ++)
 {
   var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
   checkbox.type="checkbox";
   checkbox.value=data.category_name.category_id;
   checkbox.id=data.category_name[i].category_name;

   var label= document.createElement('label');
   label.htmlFor=data.category_name[i].category_name;
   var span=document.createElement('span');
   label.appendChild(span);
   var span1=document.createElement('span');
   span1.className="check";
   label.appendChild(span1);
   var span2=document.createElement('span');
   span2.className="box";
   label.appendChild(span2);
          label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data.category_name[i].category_name));
   var div= document.createElement('div');
   div.appendChild(label);
   div.appendChild(checkbox);
   place.appendChild(div);
}
```